# Running wsl results in starting a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Anaconda under Windows and Ubuntu under WSL. I have not used this Ubuntu installation for a long time. When I tried to run Ubuntu now, I saw the following:

[image]

That is, WSL starts a Jupyter Notebook server, which I have to kill by hitting Ctrl-C to get the Ubuntu prompt. What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for something to "autostart" when running WSL:

- First, you (or an application) may have modified your startup scripts to start the Jupyter Notebook server.  To see if this is the case, try starting WSL from PowerShell by running:

  ```
  wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc
  ```

  This will run `bash` without the startup scripts.  If this brings you to the prompt without running the notebook sesrver, then the problem is in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (assuming bash is your default shell).

  Given the symptoms you are seeing, this is the most likely cause.  If that's the case, look in those files to see if you can find the line that is starting the server, and comment it out.
- Second, and related to the first, do you recall trying to enable Systemd at any point using something like Genie or WSL2Hacks?  If so, then I believe they modify your start scripts to run Systemd, which can be used to start other services.  However, I would expect those Systemd-executed services to start daemonized, in the background, and not interrupt your shell's startup.
- Under Windows 11, services can also be autostarted via `/etc/wsl.conf`, but again, they would be started by the root user in this case, and in the background.  I can't think of a non-pathological way that this could be used to interrupt the user's startup shell experience.